# Spring boot jar packing and com4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, native

Having a spring boot application containing a com4j dependency (which has a dll inside)

If I package the application as WAR, everything works as expected. If I package it as jar the dll cannot be loaded:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\<…>\interfaces.jar!\BOOT-INF\lib\com4j-x86.dll (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com4j.COM4J.loadNativeLibrary(COM4J.java:578)
    at com4j.COM4J.<clinit>(COM4J.java:531)
```

Is there something special required for the spring boot to load the library?

Comment: how do you deploy/start your war/jar?

Comment: What do you mean with package as a war. You are packaging it and deploying it as a war file or running it standalone?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, I tested it as a deployed war file on a tomcat an everything worked as expected.

Meanwile I know the workaround to unpack native libraries and put them into the same directory where I start the jar file. I suppose the issue is in the spring boot, which is unable to load native libraries out of a jar inside of a jar (hope you understand the point)

@eis : I start my jar file by javaw -jar interface.jar